# What is the negation of a logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If I have for example the following:

$p$ is $ x > 4$

$\lnot p$ is $x < 4$ ?

Comment: What if $x = 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given real numbers $a$ and $b$, exactly one of the following holds:
$$a<b$$ $$a=b$$ $$a>b$$

So the negation of any one of these is equivalent to the disjunction of the remaining two:

$$\lnot(a<b) \iff (a>b)\vee(a=b)$$
$$\lnot(a=b) \iff (a<b)\vee(a>b)$$
$$\lnot(a>b) \iff (a<b)\vee(a=b)$$

One usually sees "$a\geq b$" and "$a\leq b$" for the first and third cases. The second case is often written "$a\neq b$" for obvious reasons. Thus the symbol "$\geq$" is read "is greater than or equal to", etc.

Comment: What do you mean by the **"the negation of any one of these is equivalent to the disjunction of the remaining two"**?

Comment: @direprobs That means that if one of the statements is false, then one or the other of the remaining two must be true. ("Disjunction" is the "or" relation.)